# PowerShell return collection object as duplicates

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, office365

Hi apologies if this has been asked before. If so

I have  function that builds a object array of group members.  I can see  it works fine inside the function but the return object is has exactly double the members - tried an ArrayList and that is even worse. Can somebody please explain what is going on....

```
function Get-MsolGroupMembers
  {


  [CmdletBinding()]
  param
  (
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, Position=0)]
    [string]
    $SearchString
  )

  $groups = Get-MsolGroup -SearchString $SearchString -MaxResults 1

  $retObjs = @()

  Write-Host -fore Yellow $groups.Count 'Group(s) found'
  foreach ($group in $groups)  
  { 
    $groupGUID = $group.ObjectId 
    $groupDisplayName = $group.DisplayName 
    $groupEmail = $group.EmailAddress 
    $groupType = $group.GroupType 
    $groupMembers = Get-MsolGroupMember -GroupObjectId $groupGUID  -All


    foreach ($groupMember in $groupMembers)  
    { 
      $Properties = @{"GroupDisplayName"=$groupDisplayName; 
        "GroupEmail"=$grouEmail; 
        "GroupType"=$groupType; 
        "MemberDisplayName"=$groupMember.DisplayName; 
        "MemberEmail"=$groupMember.EmailAddress; 
      "MemberType"=$groupMember.GroupMemberType} 

      $Obj = New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property $Properties 
      Write-Output $Obj | select GroupDisplayName,GroupEmail,GroupType,MemberDisplayName,MemberEmail,MemberType 

      $retObjs += $Obj
    } 

    return $reObjs; 
  }
```

}

```
$members = Get-MsolGroupMembers -SearchString 'My Test Group'
$members.Count
```

Answer (score 2):

Sure, this is easy. You're outputting everything twice. Once with the `Write-Output` line, and then again with the `return` line. PowerShell functions return anything to the pipeline that is not specifically redirected (such as with `Write-Host` or `Export-Csv`), so both of those commands essentially do the same thing, which is where your doubling comes from. Remove one or the other and you'll be all set.

Comment: Thanks  can I remove the trailing return but still pass my collection back to the calling script.

Comment: Yes, the collection is unrolled anyway when the function outputs it, so it makes no difference either way you do it.

Comment: Thanks, I was a bit confused as I thought write-object just handled the internal population each object.  Thanks for correcting me

Comment: @westerdaled Glad it works, The best way to show recognition and tell other people that may have the same question that this answer is good is to accept it by clicking the checkmark in the answer :)